# How to access a child's inherited member from a parent's method

Tags: java, class, oop, virtual, abstract

How do I access a child class' string variable declared in its superclass?

I have classes something like these:

```
public class Parent {
  public void display() {
    // displays A
  }
}

public class Child1 extends Parent {
}

public class Child2 extends Parent {
}

Parent p1 = new Child1();
Parent p2 = new Child2();

p1.display(); // Currently displaying parent value of A
p2.display(); // Currently displaying parent value of A
```

How do I ensure that that inside this `display()`, both `p1` and `p2` use their own values for A, instead of the parent classes?

Comment: If the `Parent` class is not abstract, make a constructor which has the parameters `(String a)`. Then from the child class call `super(A)`

Comment: can you rewrite your question because i can't understand what do you mean

Comment: I've taken a stab at editing the question.  I'm sorry that it's a complete rewrite, but the original was quite hard to understand. Roll the edit back (or just update my edit) if I've the wrong end of the stick.

Comment: + to @WyattLowery comment because testability advocates condemn constructors secretly do something. It makes it hard to test.

Comment: Do you have a link to a testability advocate condemning constructors?  I'm a testability advocate and I don't condemn constructors.

Comment: @WyattLowery: *"If the Parent class is not abstract, make a constructor which has the parameters (String a)"* ... abstract classes can have constructors and instance fields just as concrete classes can.  There is no requirement that the class be concrete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm answering the question as I've edited it; apologies if I've misunderstood the question.)

The desired behaviour is the normal behaviour, so long as you're not using static members. Define the required member as `protected` in the superclass; each instance of any of the three classes will use its own value for it.

```
public class Parent {
  protected string name;

  public Parent() {
    name = "Parent's value";
  }

  public void setName(string newValue) {
    name = newValue;
  }

  public void display() {
    System.out.println(name);
  }
}

public class Child1 extends Parent {
  public Child1() {
    name = "Child1's value";
  }
}

public class Child2 extends Parent {
  public Child2() {
    name = "Child2's value";
  }
}

public static void main() {
  new Parent().display();
  new Child1().display();
  Child2 c2 = new Child2();
  c2.display();
  c2.setName("New name!");
  c2.display();
}
```

This produces the expected output:

```
Parent's value
Child1's value
Child2's value
New name!
```

Comment: If variable is a part of constructor, it would enforce child classes to use a different variable always when they instantiate; Do you think that limits flexibility; I would like to know your comments on using a getName() method in parent, and overriding it, as outlined above in my response.

Comment: Using `getName()` in parent is just fine.  But there is no point in having more than one declaration of the `name` member or more than one definition of the `getName()` method. They can both be done in Parent. The subclasses don't need any special code.

Comment: "If variable is a part of constructor, it would enforce child classes to use a different variable always when they instantiate".  This is not correct, it doesn't enforce anything. You might have a `setName()` method or simple use the property directly. In my example code, `Child1` and `Child2` update the `name` property directly. You do not need a different variable.

Comment: *"If variable is a part of constructor, it would enforce child classes to use a different variable always when they instantiate; Do you think that limits flexibility? "* ... it does not, or at least it needn't.  It is impossible to generalize an answer to this question.  You have a problem to solve -> you develop a problem domain -> you develop an object model that serves your problem domain.  If you have an "is a" relationship in your object model that is supported by different constructor types in the child classes, then you've done exactly what you should have done.

Comment: @PaulHicks, scottb: Apologies. I meant, if 'variable is a constructor arg', and not 'inside constructor'.

Comment: cool, I didnt think of using a getter for the value since I was using the value inside the parent class. Once I did that it used the child's value like it was supposed to, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

There's one very common way to do this. This is a java 'pattern'. This technique is a driving example of the use getter/setter methods in object oriented design.

Declare abstract getter/setter methods for value A in the parent *and* fully define them in the child classes. The parent uses the getter/setters universally to access the value.

In this way, the parent, and the children, will always be utilizing the 'A' value as declared, managed, and updated in the child class. The getters and setters must not be static (of course, that makes no sense). This method allows the parent and child classes to remain independent and the children can be modified/adjusted in a very flexible and clean manner. In particular, the child classes need not maintain A actively, and can calculate, double check, or delegate the request for A in a JIT (just-in-time) fashion.

**COMPLETE EXAMPLE:**

```
public abstract class Parent {
  // These two methods must be overridden by all child classes. Compiler enforces that.
  public abstract int getA();
  public abstract int setA( int newA );
        // This display routine utilizes the *childs* a
  public void display() { someoutput.write( this.getA() ); }
}

public class Child1 extends Parent {
  SomeFancyOrPartularFormOfA a = null; // a Jazzy type of A, used by parent.
  @Override // Let java and IDEs know we intend to override it.
  public int getA() { return( this.a.gatherorcalcA() ); }
  @Override // Let java and IDEs know we intend to override it.
  public int setA( int newA ) { this.a.setorincorporateA( newA ); }
   . . .
}
public class Child2 extends Parent {
  Integer a = 0;  // A more mundane type of A, still used by parent.
  @Override // Let java and IDEs know we intend to override it.
  public int getA() { return( this.a ); }
  @Override // Let java and IDEs know we intend to override it.
  public int setA( int newA ) { this.a = newA; }
   . . .
}
```

Comment: hollywood principle/template method pattern?

Comment: Yes, this is a narrowing of the Template Method, gang of 4 "Design Patterns". In this simpler variation, the subclasses redefine the storage and management of data more than the algorithm itself.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively if there is a method to get the value of A, like `getA()` in `class Parent`, override the method in each of the `class Child1` and `class Child2` to return their respective A values.

I reused example by @paul-hicks, and demo-ed my approach below:

```
public class Parent
    ...
    public void display() {
      System.out.println(getA());
    }

    protected String getName() {
      return "parent";
    }
}

class Child1 {
   ...
   protected String getName() {
      return "child1";
   }
}

class Child2 {
   ...
   protected String getName() {
      return "child2";
   }
}
```

Comment: This version does not use any fields/members, just constants.  That is extremely inflexible. If `getName()` would actually be returning a `name` member, then it's the same as my answer. I just took a shortcut for the purposes of the example: I used a protected member instead of an accessor. Same-same but different.

Comment: @PaulHicks When you pointed my version does not use fields/members, I realise I digressed. You have written an example code for the benefit of the person asking this question, and I digressed towards the design aspect of that. Yes, it is same-same.